# Where did the add server option go?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

BuildNotifications.exe used to have an [Add server option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719922/57883), where/when did it go away and how do I add additional servers/tfs machines to listen to now?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it through the Normal Visual Studio connect dialogue. The Build Notification tool uses the same config as Visual Studio. Adding an additional server through Visual Studio will allow the server to show up in the build notification tool.

Inside the build notification tool you can right click on a server and select Disable to stop monitoring that particular server, or you can monitor multiple builds from multiple servers.

Removing the server through the VS dialogue will remove that server from the Build Notification tool aswell